# Determine the right tablet browser resolution for webdesign

Tags: android, css, developer-tools

How can you determine the effective browser resolution (for CSS) of Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 (or any other tablets)?

The specifications say that the resolution is 1920 x 1200. So I designed an application that will run on 800+ Samsung Galaxy tablets. Now I see that the resolution is wrong and I can't get the right resolution from the internet. Of course the app is responsive but I would like to make use of a testing tool in the browser.

My goal is to add this correctly to my Chrome developer console.
[image]

Specs: http://www.samsung.com/uk/tablets/galaxy-tab-a-10-1-2016-t580/SM-T580NZKABTU/

Answer (score 2):

A very cheap means of finding your device's web browser resolution could be to simply determine it's viewport dimension.

While there are a ton of apps out there to get the information for you, a basic website such as http://www.mydevice.io/ can help out with this.
This website should also help give comparisons of other devices if you don't have the device yourself.

I would presume the Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1  should be 800 x 1280 for CSS media queries.